# Every time I connect my Android to my Ubuntu it asks me to allow the connection, can I change that?

Tags: usb, samsung-galaxy-j7

I have a Galaxy J7 and Ubuntu 16.04 on my Linux box.

Every time I connect the phone to the computer, it asks me to `ALLOW` the connection.

Is there a way to add an authorization for that one computer to connect automatically and without an `ALLOW` each time it connects?

I found a couple of answers to similar questions, but from like 2010 and 2012. The answers on those did not seem to make any sense for the J7.

Comment: Do I have to install something to get these "developer options"?

Comment: Ah, wow! Clicking 7 times... Ha! Ha! It says "Build Number" btw, I'll see next time and disconnect/re-connect, but that has been annoying me quite a bit! This time it asked me to authorized only once. Much better already.

Comment: Okay, so that solution works good enough. It looks like I just have to click `ALLOW` once. Before it would require me to click it over and over again until Ubuntu and Android were in sync. or something of the sort...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revoking USB authorisation in developer settings (enabled by tapping "Build number" 7 times ) fixed the problem [for OP](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/177265/every-time-i-connect-my-android-to-my-ubuntu-it-asks-me-to-allow-the-connection?noredirect=1#comment227436_177265) and they needed to authorise only once and not on each time it was connected, as earlier

Probably it was because of authorisation being "forgotten" on the device or a handshake issue between PC and device

Comment: Yeah, most certainly a handshake issue with Ubuntu... Unfortunate. I hope it gets fixed one day, in the meantime I can use the developer mode.